# Resolving relative file paths with webpack and react outside of app root

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have the current app structure for a React app with a shared `common` folder:

```
- app
    - ui
        - common
            - helpers
                - test.js
        - web
            - src
                - index.js
            - webpack
                - webpack.config.js
```

I'm attempting to wire up my webpack 1 config such that in my react app I can do a relative import of `import { someMethod } from 'common/helpers'` but I have been unable to manage it thus far.

I've tried adding:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
      common: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..'),
      // and, at a different time
      common: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'common')
    },
    // ...
    root: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..'),
      // and at a differnt time 
      common: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'common'),
      srcPath
    ],
```

as well as `moduleLoaders`, but none have worked. I always keep getting:

`Error: Cannot find module 'common/helpers'`

is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: `import { someMethod } from 'common/helpers'` but `helpers` is a folder. You cannot import a folder?!

Comment: Btw. Webpack 3 is out and 4 is coming... ;-)

Comment: v4 is already out too, released 5 days ago.. :-), but I would stick to v3 yet.

Comment: just referencing a folder should auto import `index.js` no? even If i were to do `import { someMethod } from 'common/helpers/index.js' it still fails.

Comment: absolute imports seem to work fine, i'm just trying to clean it up with relative. ie: `../../common/helpers'` works fine.

Comment: `index.js` should work I think, never tried it, but I am not sure for `file.js`.
I don't know which additional conventions apply behind the scene..